# Use Post or PostAndAsyncReply with F#'s MailboxProcessor?

Tags: concurrency, f#, actor, mailboxprocessor

I've seen different snippets demonstrating a `Put` message that returns `unit` with F#'s `MailboxProcessor`. In some, only the `Post` method is used while others use `PostAndAsyncReply`, with the reply channel immediately replying once the message is being processed. In doing some testing, I found a significant time lag when awaiting the reply, so it seems that unless you need a real reply, you should use `Post`.

Note: I started asking this in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8482495/29439) but thought it useful to post as a full question. In the other thread, Tomas Petricek mentioned that the reply channel could be used a wait mechanism to ensure the caller delayed until the `Put` message was processed.

Does using `PostAndAsyncReply` help with message ordering, or is it just to force a pause until the first message is processed? In terms of performance `Post` appears the right solution. Is that accurate?

**Update:**

I just thought of a reason why `PostAndAsyncReply` might be necessary in the [`BlockingQueueAgent` example](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Async/Agents/BlockingQueueAgent.fs): `Scan` is used to find `Get` messages when the queue is full, so you don't want to `Put` and then `Get` before the previous `Put` has completed.

Comment: Doesn't it come down to whether or not you need a reply? Or am I missing something?

Comment: "so it seems that unless you need a real reply, you should use `Post`." Is that your question?  If so then yes.  I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to get at.  Is your concern just performance?

Comment: Here's the source FWIW https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/control.fs

Comment: I updated the question a bit to try to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I generally agree with your summary - it makes sense that `PostAndAsyncReply` is slower than `Post`, so if the caller doesn't need to get a notification from the agent when the operation (such as putting value into the queue) completes, it should definitely expose a way to do that using just `Post`. The fact that `PostAndAsyncReply` is a lot slower probably means that some agents should expose both options and let the caller decide.

Regarding the specific example of `BlockingQueueAgent` (or a similar one that I used to implement one-place buffer), the typical application of the agent is to solve the consumer-producer problem. In consumer-producer problem, we want to block the producer when the queue is full and block the consumer when it is empty. The .NET `BlockingCollection` supports only synchronous blocking, which is a bit bad (i.e. it can block the whole thread pool).

The using the `BlockingQueueAgent` that sends the `Put` messsage using `PostAndAsyncReply`, we can wait until the element is added to the queue asynchronously (so it blocks the producer, but without blocking threads!) An example of typical usage is the [image processing pipeline](http://tomasp.net/blog/parallel-extra-image-pipeline.aspx) that I wrote some time ago. Here is one snippet from that:

```
// Phase 2: Scale to a thumbnail size and add frame
let scalePipelinedImages = async {
   while true do 
     let! info = loadedImages.AsyncGet()
     scaleImage info
     do! scaledImages.AsyncAdd(info) }
```

This loop repeatedly gets an image from the `loadedImages` queue, does some processing and writes the result to `scaledImages`. The blocking using the queue (both when reading and when writing) controls the parallelism, so that the steps of pipeline run in parallel, but it does not keep loading more and more images if the pipeline cannot handle them at the required speed.

Answer (score 5):

My advice is to design your system so you can use `Post` as much as possible.

This technology was designed for asynchronous concurrency where the objective is to fire-and-forget messages. The idea of waiting for a response goes directly against the grain of this.